# Call methods in list except for methods specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of methods and I can call all of the methods at once with another method.

How can I call the method which contains all while leaving out certain items(or methods) from the list?  I can currently specify one to leave out.  I am not sure how to leave out more than one.  Here is what I am working with:

```
class SomeClass:
    def method_a(self):
        print('method_a')

    def method_b(self):
        print('method_b')

    def method_c(self):
        print('method_c')

    def method_runner(self, skip_name='' ):
        for m in [self.method_a, self.method_b, self.method_c]:
            if m.__name__ != skip_name:
                m()
```

Now I can do this:

```
>>> some_obj = SomeClass()
>>> some_obj.method_runner('')
method_a
method_b
method_c
>>> some_obj.method_runner('method_a')
method_b
method_c
>>> some_obj.method_runner('method_b')
method_a
method_c
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
class SomeClass:
    def method_a(self):
        print('method_a')

    def method_b(self):
        print('method_b')

    def method_c(self):
        print('method_c')

    def method_runner(self, skip_name='', skip_name2='', skip_name3=''):
        for m in [self.method_a, self.method_b, self.method_c]:
            options = [skip_name, skip_name2, skip_name3]
            for o in options:
                if m.__name__ != o:
                    m()
```

And specify more than one method to get an outcome such as:

```
>>> some_obj.method_runner('method_a', 'method_c')
method_b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
def method_runner(self, *skip_list):
        for m in [self.method_a, self.method_b, self.method_c]:
            if m.__name__ not in skip_list:
                m()
```

The `*` means varying number of arguments.

If you do not want to type the method names manually, you can use this:

```
def method_runner(self, *skip_list):
    methods = [f for f in map(lambda x: getattr(self,x), dir(self)) if callable(f) and f.__name__ != 'method_runner']
    for m in methods:
        if m.__name__ not in skip_list:
            m()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are at least to straightforward approaches. The most straightforward is for the parameter accept a container of objects to skip:

```
def method_runner(self, skipnames):
    for m in [self.method_a, self.method_b, self.method_c]:
        if m.__name__ not in skipnames:
            m()
```

And you would call by passing an appropriate container (in this case a `set` but a `list` or `tuple` might do):

```
SomeClass().method_runner({'method_a', 'method_c'})
```

But it *sounds* like you'd rather use variable-length arguments:

```
def method_runner(self, *skipnames):
    for m in [self.method_a, self.method_b, self.method_c]:
        if m.__name__ not in skipnames:
            m(self)
```

Which you could then call like this:

```
SomeClass().method_runner('method_a', 'method_c')
```

However, `skipnames` will now always be a tuple, which might not have the performance characteristics you require.

As recommended by @ChristianDean you may want to make your list of methods a class variable:

```
In [7]: class SomeClass:
   ...:     def method_a(self):
   ...:         print('method_a')
   ...:
   ...:     def method_b(self):
   ...:         print('method_b')
   ...:
   ...:     def method_c(self):
   ...:         print('method_c')
   ...:
   ...:     _my_methods = method_a, method_b, method_c
   ...:
   ...:     def method_runner(self, skipnames):
   ...:         for m in self._my_methods:
   ...:             if m.__name__ not in skipnames:
   ...:                 m(self)
   ...:

In [8]: SomeClass().method_runner({'method_a', 'method_c'})
method_b
```

Just note, you'd have to pass `self` to the function manually, because it is not a method!

Comment: @KadeWilliams in a function definition signature, means [variable number arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: +1 I would also recommend making the list `[self.method_a, self.method_b, self.method_c]` a class variable. One can then avoid wasting time reconstructing the same list each time `method_runner` is called.

Comment: You can trivially turn your tuple into a set if performance is a concern. How many methods can a class have though?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, likely it won't make an appreciable difference either way.